# Get a sharepoint list item entities like (Title , Department and position)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, jsom

Using the codes below I have already extracted the Email, `DisplayName` and loginName, but how can I extract the Department/Position. `get_department` doesn't work.

```
var item;
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("JTESTING");
item = list.getItemById(50);
clientContext.load(item);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
function(){ // successfully retrieved value from list item
var firstThru = item.get_item("Name");
var user = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(firstThru.get_lookupValue());
          clientContext.load(user);
          clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
               function(){ // successfully ensured user from user name
                    var email = user.get_email();
                    var login = user.get_loginName();
                    var displayName = user.get_title();
                    alert("User LoginName: " + login + "\nUser Email: " + email + "\nUser Display Name: " + displayName);
               },function(sender,args){ // on error
                    alert(args.get_message());
               }
          );
     },function(sender,args){ // on error
          alert(args.get_message());
     }
);
```

Comment: Hi, Please don't forget the **Mark** the correct and helpful answer as accepted, thank you for your contributions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the web.get_siteUserInfoList() to retrieve the User Information

```
 getUserInfo(userName,Success,Error)
{
   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var userInfoList = context.get_web().get_siteUserInfoList();
   var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
   var viewXml = "<View> \
                    <Query> \
                       <Where> \
                           <Eq><FieldRef Name='UserName' /><Value Type='Text'>" + userName + "</Value></Eq> \
                       </Where>  \
                    </Query> \
                    <RowLimit>1</RowLimit> \
                  </View>";
   query.set_viewXml(viewXml);
   var items = userInfoList.getItems(query);
   context.load(items,'Include(Deleted,Department,EMail,FirstName,ID,IsActive,IsSiteAdmin,JobTitle,LastName,MobilePhone,Name,Notes,Office,Picture,SipAddress,UserName,WebSite,WorkPhone)');
   context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       if(items.get_count() > 0) {
          var item = items.itemAt(0);
          Success(item.get_fieldValues());
       }
       else {
          Success(null);
       }   
     },
     Error
   );
}



//Usage
getUserInfo('username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com',function(userInfo){
       console.log('User Id: ' + userInfo.ID);
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `sp.userprofiles.js` to fetch these properties.

For that you need to use the `peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor` method, pass the login name of the user and then specify the properties that you want.

Try and modify the below code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function(){
        SP.SOD.registerSod("sp.userprofiles.js", SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl("sp.userprofiles.js"));
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.userprofiles.js", "SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager", getData);
});

function getData(){

    var item;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("JTESTING");
    item = list.getItemById(50);
    clientContext.load(item);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){ 
        // successfully retrieved value from list item
        var firstThru = item.get_item("Name");
        var user = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(firstThru.get_lookupValue());
                  clientContext.load(user);
                  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){ 
                            // successfully ensured user from user name
                            var email = user.get_email();
                            var login = user.get_loginName();
                            var displayName = user.get_title();
                            console.log("User LoginName: " + login + "\nUser Email: " + email + "\nUser Display Name: " + displayName);

                            getUserDetails(login);

                       },function(sender,args){ // on error
                            console.log(args.get_message());
                       }
                  );
             },function(sender,args){ // on error
                  console.log(args.get_message());
             }
        );
}

function getUserDetails(login){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 

    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);   

    var userProfileProperties = [];

    userProfileProperties[0] = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(login, 'Title'); 
    userProfileProperties[1] = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(login, 'Department');
    userProfileProperties[2] = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(login, 'WorkEmail');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){

        console.log("Job Title - " + userProfileProperties[0].get_value());
        console.log("Department - " + userProfileProperties[1].get_value());
        console.log("Email - " + userProfileProperties[2].get_value());

    },function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}
```